# How to setup fragment projects

Tags: codenameone

I'm using Eclipse with the Codename One Plugin.

Now I am starting a second project.

I would like to setup one or more "fragment" projects to avoid code duplication between projects. For example if I'm having a utility class for string concatenation I'd like to have this in a Utilities fragment project which then would be referenced by my projects.

What is the recommended way of doing this with Codename One?

Answer (score 0):

For Codename One that's a [cn1lib](https://www.codenameone.com/cn1libs.html) unfortunately at this time the Eclipse plugin is the only one that doesn't support the creation of a cn1lib (although it allows using them just fine).

Since a cn1lib is just an Ant project you can just download an existing project and put in your own code instead of what's there.

Comment: The projects I look at are NetBeans projects and I think I don't like the idea of creating a cn1lib to use it in other projects. Ideally my fragment projects were just in the classpath of the projects I am working on. This works fine with eclipses internal builder. But the configured "jar_project" builder apparently does not use the build path eclipse uses.

Comment: You can change the target build XML to do whatever you want but since that's not the official approach it might fail. Notice that even though the cn1libs are netbeans projects they are still just ant projects that should work in every IDE and command line.